Term for pronouncing every letter, like t in water
Native USA English speakers frequently skip (or elide?) certain letters, like the t in water, and modify others.
What is a term for someone who (self-consciously?) pronounces every voiceable letter?
P.S. My apologies if I've asked this before. I thought I had and cannot find it.

I don't understand what you mean. Nobody "pronounces letters".

Someone using unclipped vowels.

Well, you’ve got it tagged as over-enunciation. Conscious enunciation may also work. You need more?

In BrE too, some people say "wa-er" instead of "water". If there is a word for someone who speaks clearly, it might be prejudice by another who thinks their own speech is normal (as we all do). Self-conscious? Someone who habitually drops their aitches might self-consciously add an h where is it not normally used.

Nobody pronounces every letter in every word. For example oeuvre and putsch.

American speakers do pronounce the 't' in water; it's just that that 't' makes a [ɾ] sound, rather than a [t] sound. (Just like how the 't' in "tip" makes a [tʰ] sound rather than a [t] sound.) Nobody pronounces the every phoneme the same way in every context.

@alphabet some pronounce it as a glottal stop, but I suspect that this is far more prevalent in England than in the US.

@WeatherVane also "shall" and "heath" -- there's no need here for recourse to borrowed words that retain their foreign spelling.
.

It’s a form of “affected speech.”

Why stop at affected when there's the chance to be pedantic and pretentious?

It could be classed as speaking clearly, but definitely can be pedantic depending on exactly how you do it. If you pronounce the /d/ in every "and" and the /t/ in every "to", you might just be a non-native speaker.

Irritating, tiresome...?

Speaking clearly. The people who pronounce the /t/ in "water", or who use a glottal stop there, don't necessarily also pronounce a /d/ in every "and". Eliding it, or reducing it to a barely-noticeable sound, is an American accent feature. This web site is not solely for discussing American accents.

Native Hawaiian is unusual in its articulation of phones. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_phonology

There is no term for pronouncing every letter in English. Because in English, more often than not, every letter is not pronounced. Pronunciation ≠ Spelling. I don't know what voiceable means in the question.

Listen to the clear speech from Meryl Streep: at 11:23 she says better. No bedder for her. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i8xX_zsacWI She has one little stumble at totalitarian. But overall, it's so very clear.

Overarticulation and hyperarticulation are terms used to describe this deliberate and exaggerated speech, often observed in infants or language learners. These terms can also apply to specific dialectal speech patterns. Wiktionary provides similar definitions for both terms:

exaggerated articulation 
   the hyperarticulation of child-directed speech
hyperarticulation/Wiktionary


excessive articulation
overarticulation/Wiktionary

These terms are also used in academic publications in the field of linguistics. For example:

The ability of speakers to exaggerate speech sounds ("hyperarticulation") has led to the theory that the targets themselves must be hyperspace hyperarticulated.
Whalen DH, Magen HS, Pouplier M, Kang AM, Iskarous K. Vowel production and perception: hyperarticulation without a hyperspace effect. Lang Speech. 2004;47(Pt 2):155-74. doi: 10.1177/00238309040470020301. PMID: 15581190.

When discussing language orthography, this phenomenon can be related to phonemic orthography. English, for instance, is highly non-phonemic compared to many languages but was mostly phonemic during the Middle English period. Languages such as Serbo-Croatian and Esperanto are often cited as examples of employing ideally phonemic orthography.

A phonemic orthography is an orthography (system for writing a language) in which the graphemes (written symbols) correspond consistently to the language's phonemes (the smallest units of speech that can differentiate words).
Wikipedia


This does not answer the question. The OP is not asking an academic question. It's about good diction.

@Lambie Surely not, because pronouncing every letter results in bad diction, not good diction.

@alphabet Questions can be naive when people don't know exactly how to say something. That's the case here. So rather than go off on tangents and over the moon, it's best in my view to help them say what they really mean but don't know how to say. Obviously, no one pronounces every letter in English. We all know that that is inaccurate. The OP does not. Getting into the phonetic weeds is not what he is looking for (which can be seen from the rest of his question.).

The term would be "articulate."
M-W gives as one of the definitions:

intransitive verb
1
: to utter clear and understandable sounds


Yes, but your answer is too short and has no back-up stuff. :)

Merriam Webster:

enunciate transitive verb
2: articulate, pronounce - enunciate all the syllables
Yoshioka, as well, has always striven to make sure that her vowels are enunciated and the melody shines through clearly. — Billboard
Japan, Billboard, 13 Nov. 2023

Collins on line

enunciate (ɪnʌnsieɪt)

verb When you enunciate a word or part of a word, you pronounce it clearly.

[formal]
His voice was harsh as he enunciated each word carefully.
She enunciates very slowly and carefully.

